# UEFI - Black screen when attempting to install UBUNTU

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, 13.10, uefi

Today, I received my new Packard Bell EN TE69BM. The Laptop comes with garbage aka Windows 8. I want to install Ubuntu on it. Unfortunately the BIOS is set up to boots the flash drive in EFI mode and this setting cannot be changed. I've tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 but to no avail. (SECURE BOOT is OFF) 
I get the options:

- try ubuntu without installing
- install ubuntu
- check disk for defects

No matter what I select, I simply get a never changing black screen no matter how long I wait.
I have the latest BIOS installed on the device.

I've tried the following:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

but it did not work!

Any way to get Ubuntu working on my notebook?

Comment: I checked that out. The solution did not get me anywhere

Comment: Also look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported for many possible issues with UEFI install.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible "black screen" causes. The post to which user68186 linked has many possible solutions, and I suspect that you haven't tried all of them. In brief, some solutions that are most likely to work include:

- Using the `nomodeset` kernel option at boot time
- Using the brightness control on your laptop (sometimes the system comes up dimmed)
- Using a more recent distribution (14.04 is coming out on the 17th, so trying the current beta, or the RC that's coming out on Thursday, is worth the effort)

You could also try installing the server version, which uses the (usually less finicky) text mode for installation. If that works, then typing `sudo apt-get install unity` will install most (maybe all) of the desktop stuff. This will at least put you in a better position for further debugging, since you'll be able to hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a text-mode login if it doesn't work at that point.